# Stripping substring from string in filepath

Tags: bash

I have the path to a directory, like this:

```
DIRNAME=/path/to/projects/proj1/dir1
```

I want strip everything after `projects`, but keep `projects` in the file path. However, this code does not work:

```
DIRNAME=/path/to/projects/proj1/dir1
My_Dir=projects

echo ${DIRNAME%$My_Dir*}
```

This returns `/path/to/`; I want to return `/path/to/projects` instead. Nothing after `projects` in the file path is static and thus cannot be used in the substring match as per this example.

Obligatory sidenote: I have read over a dozen different pages with multiple examples each of substring manipulation but have not been able to find one that shows how to do this. I think `sed` might be able to do something like this but I haven't seen any examples that do this.

Comment: My usual solution in this kind of scenario is to just do something like this: ${DIRNAME%$My_Dir*}/$My_Dir

Comment: Maybe you can use ${DIRNAME%$proj1*}, so this would return /path/to/projects/

Comment: ...by the way -- this may or may not be entirely under your control, but using all-caps names for your own variables is contrary to POSIX-established conventions (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, see fourth paragraph), which reserve all-caps names for system use and suggest that application-controlled names should have at least one lower-case character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally how I would pull apart directories in this kind of situation:

```
DIRNAME=/path/to/projects/proj1/dir1
My_Dir=projects

PROJROOT=${DIRNAME%$My_Dir*}$My_Dir
PROJDIR=${DIRNAME#*$PROJROOT}

echo $DIRNAME
echo $PROJROOT
echo $PROJDIR
```

The output for this is:

```
/path/to/projects/proj1/dir1
/path/to/projects
/proj1/dir1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful, but you can make the shell substitution work.  For example:

```
keep="projects"
base="${DIRNAME%/$keep/*}/$keep"
```

Note that the `/$keep/` part ensures that you get the right path with `/path/to/projects/with/remote_projects_here/to/confuse/you`; your original would mismanage that string.

You can also do it with `sed`:

```
base=$(sed "s%\(.*/$keep\)/.*%\1%" <<< "$DIRNAME")
```

using a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings); or you could do it the portable and classic way with `echo`:

```
base=$(echo "$DIRNAME" | sed "s%\(.*/$keep\)/.*%\1%")
```

Of course, you can still run into problems with what's in the sub-directory names:

```
/path/to/projects/with/remote_projects_here/projects/select
```

---

Test code:

```
#!/bin/bash

My_Dir=projects
keep="projects"
for dir in \
    /path/to/projects/proj1/dir1 \
    /path/to/projects/with/remote_projects_here/to/confuse/you
do
    DIRNAME="$dir"

    echo "Data"
    echo "$DIRNAME"

    echo "Original"
    echo "${DIRNAME%$My_Dir*}"

    echo "Variant 1"
    base="${DIRNAME%/$keep/*}/$keep"
    echo "$base"

    echo "Variant 2"
    base=$(sed "s%\(.*/$keep\)/.*%\1%" <<< "$DIRNAME")
    echo "$base"

    echo "Variant 3"
    base=$(echo "$DIRNAME" | sed "s%\(.*/$keep\)/.*%\1%")
    echo "$base"
done
```

Example output:

```
Data
/path/to/projects/proj1/dir1
Original
/path/to/
Variant 1
/path/to/projects
Variant 2
/path/to/projects
Variant 3
/path/to/projects
Data
/path/to/projects/with/remote_projects_here/to/confuse/you
Original
/path/to/projects/with/remote_
Variant 1
/path/to/projects
Variant 2
/path/to/projects
Variant 3
/path/to/projects
```

The output could be better formatted, but it makes the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR=/path/to/projects/proj1/dir1 

dirname "$DIR"
basename "$DIR"
```

outputs

```
/path/to/projects/proj1
dir1
```

so you can concatenate these with a slash, and you're done. I think the simplest way is this.

Comment: Quotes -- `basename "$DIR"`, `dirname "$DIR"`.

Comment: Try testing again with directory names that contain spaces.

Comment: ...and that's only one pathological case out of many. For instance, one can run `mkdir '*'` to create a directory named `*`; you might look at how your code works (without the quotes) with that, too.

Comment: I didn't understand your last example but, I tried this DIR=/path/to/projects\ /proj1/dir1, after projects it has a space, but it's working. I really couldn't see why it's not working with spaces, can you please give an example input? So I can learn.

Comment: When I run `DIR=/path/to/projects\ /proj1/dir1; dirname $DIR`, I get `usage: dirname path` (on MacOS X).

Comment: ...and when I run `DIR=/path/to/projects\ /proj1/dir1; dirname $DIR` on a Linux system with GNU tools, I get two separate lines of output, `/path/to` and `/proj1`. Which is what I expect, since the shell is breaking the expanded value into two arguments and passing them separately.

Comment: ...whereas if you run `dirname "$DIR"`, that suppresses both string-splitting and glob-expansion behaviors, so the shell is guaranteed to pass the exact contents of the variable to the `dirname` command.

Comment: ...by the way, if you were testing on zfs rather than bash or POSIX sh you'd see different behavior -- ZFS doesn't do string-splitting unless explicitly requested.

Comment: OK, it's seems quotes provide cross-platform error proof, got it. Upvoting your comment.

Comment: `DIR="/Users/Awkward Squad/External Projects"` gives trouble.  On an ancient RHEL 5 system, `dirname $DIR` yields three lines of output:
`/Users`, `Squad`, and `.`, while `basename $DIR` yields an error message over two lines (`basename: extra operand ‘Projects’` and 
`Try 'basename --help' for more information.`).  Neither is really what you're after.  By contrast: `basename "$DIR"` yields
`External Projects` and
`dirname "$DIR"` yields
`/Users/Awkward Squad`.

Comment: But should't you give input like, "/Users/Awkward\ Squad/External\ Projects"
I think you should use escape char for spaces.

Comment: @Saibot, using quotes surrounding a string is just as valid as escape characters inline.